# The page isn't redirecting properly - after upgrade from 1.7 to 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, error, upgrade, redirect

I have recently upgraded from 1.7 to 1.9 and now if I go to login or checkout, customer account ect I get the following error:

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Admin works fine. Any Ideas what could be causing this?

I used these instructions :

- [magento-how-to-safely-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9](http://sherodesigns.com/magento-how-to-safely-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9/)
- [streetdecals.co.uk](http://streetdecals.co.uk)

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: 2015-03-10T13:15:30+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store::setWebsite() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given, called in /var/sites/s/streetdecals.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 634 and defined  in /var/sites/s/streetdecals.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php on line 453

Comment: I am assuming you updated your theme files for 1.9? They will not be the same

Comment: The Theme files would have remained as I undertook a merge. A copy of 1.9 over the top of 1.7

Comment: So you updated you theme templates with the new version from 1.9?

Comment: i have a multi-store with 4 other sites under my main one and they all work OK - two of which use the same theme - the other one works so not the theme

Comment: ok so this sounds like a database issue if your other themes are working. Have you checked your urls are all correct?

Comment: And you re-indexed?

Comment: I have narrowed it down to https secure URL. My other sites are test only http and work whatever theme is being used

Comment: This may be due to the way my multi-site works I have this is my index.php /* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'streetdecals.co.uk':
    case 'www.streetdecals.co.uk':
        $mageRunCode = 'base';
        $mageRunType = 'website';
    break;
    
 break;
 case 'teebomb.co.uk':
 case 'www.teebomb.co.uk':
  $mageRunCode = 'teebomb';
  $mageRunType = 'website';
}

Comment: ok but I get an error on your regular link http://streetdecals.co.uk/pimp-your-ride

Comment: Yes you are right all top level menu items through an error.  i am going to roll it back to 1.7 and then attempt another method of upgrade - thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I go to login or checkout, customer account ect I get the following error:

That's an infinite redirect for secure base urls. Usually caused by an incompatible combination of the "Secure base url" setting and a webserver redirect rule (i.e. `.htaccess`)

For example, one redirects from https to http, the other from http to https.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have deleted

```
app/etc/use_cache.ser
```

Make sure you have cleared or disabled your cache

Remove any cache folders from var/cache

If you have APC, REDIS or some other third party cache, please flush

EDIT:

I found this in addition to the above

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```